# How to disable autocompletion on datepicker format

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, datepicker

I have a date picker which has a control template to set the string format of the date displayed in the textbox

```
<DatePicker x:Name="CustomDatePicker" BorderBrush="LightGray">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                        Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}, TargetNullValue=''}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Everything is ok except when the user tries to modify the date textually.

For example:

If we set "01/01/201", it would autocomplete to "01/01/0201" (by adding a 0 at the beginning)

If we set "01/01/9", it would autocomplete to "01/01/2009"

All this to say that this autocompletion feature is not intuitive and predictable, so I would like to disable it.

If the user put invalid date format (if there is no 4 digits in the year part for ex), I would rather display an error ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can just turn off user input

Comment: @S.Petrosov I would like to keep the user input though :/

Comment: Why would someone enter `201` as a year? *"not intuitive and predictable"* - people will start entering `201` in `2201`, the current behavior is based around `2000`-`2099` years, nobody think further, you shouldn't as well.

Comment: It's not about someone entering on purpose "201". It's more like he intended to put "2017", but he backspaced the 7 accidentally and he didn't realize it.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [`DatePicker`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DatePicker.cs) source code, it looks like the true cause for this behavior is `DateTime.Parse()` method which is used by [`ParseText()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DatePicker.cs,024d4244fc8e9785) to convert to selected-date.

You can override this behavior by extending the `DatePicker` control and pre-validating the text before it reaches `ParseText()` method.

```
public class ExtendedDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    TextBox _textBox = null;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        //subscribe to preview-lost-focus event
        _textBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") as DatePickerTextBox;
        _textBox.AddHandler(TextBox.PreviewLostKeyboardFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_PreviewLostFocus), true);
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ValdateText(_textBox.Text);
    }

    private void ValdateText(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            return;

        // ---- Add/update your valid date-formats here ----
        string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy",
                "MM/dd/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy"};

        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
        DateTime temp;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, formats, culture, styles, out temp))
        { 
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            //raise date-picker validation error event like ParseText does
            DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs dateValidationError = 
                new DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs(new FormatException("String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."), text);
            OnDateValidationError(dateValidationError);

            _textBox.Text = string.Empty; //suppress parsing in base control by emptying text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I'll try this next week and I'll keep you informed :)